# MySQL Select different data in same row into same Query

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL now. And I want to know more about OUTER JOIN with subqueries. So it means i dont want to use CASE and IF

So now I have a two tables that looks like this.

`customer` table with c_id and c_name, `order` table with order_id, c_id, order_type. There are only three kind values for order_type, 'a','b','c'

Now I want to make a summary that shows the order detail for the customer.

The table should looks like this

```
c_name   a  b  c
person1  1  0  2
person2  0  1  2 
person3  0  0  0
```

This is what i have so far

```
SELECT c.c_id, COUNT(A), COUNT(B) , COUNT(C) 
FROM customer as c

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT c_id, order_type as A FROM order
WHERE order_type = 'a')
AS first
ON first.c_id = c.c_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT c_id, order_type as B FROM order
WHERE order_type = 'b')
AS second
ON second.c_id = c.c_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT c_id, order_type as C FROM order
WHERE order_type = 'c')
AS third
ON third.c_id = c.c_id

group by c_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    c.c_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.order_type = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.order_type = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.order_type = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN order o
    ON c.c_id = o.c_id
GROUP BY
    c.c_id;
```

The idea here is to join your two tables together and then aggregate by customer, generating the totals for each type of order using `CASE` expressions.